# Set max_execution_time for view?

Tags: 7, views, configuration

I've got a view that generates a CSV report on user information. However, due to the size of the dataset it's causing the server to timeout. Is there some way that I can set the `max_execution_time()` or `set_time_limit()` just for this path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a custom-code centric path. Both [D7](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7.x-3.x) & [D8](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/8.6.x) provide a `hook_views_pre_execute()` hook. It will trigger prior to any view query execution.

You can hook into this function, inspect `$view` object for the particular view you're wanting to extend your PHP execution, then call the PHP function of your choice.

Comment: Ah interesting, never thought to use that hook for abitrary code execution, only for code relating the view itself. So I should be able to just run `set_time_limit(0)` within the hook?

Comment: Yup, if you look at the docs example, you can see it hinting at the same idea (noting an admin of heavy query). You should be able to execute any PHP code you need. As long as `set_time_limit()` is allowed on your host machine, you should be able to run it.

Comment: Seems like the right way to do this in general, but hitting a timeout on cloudflare now. May just need to set something up through Batch API. Thanks for the suggestion, though!